# conditional select using multiple if conditions

Tags: sql

I have rows in a table `Players` like this.

```
+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  USERNAME | A  | B  | C  | D  | E  | F  | G  | H  |
+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   Mike    | 45 | 34 | 56 | 58 | 29 | 74 | 39 | 48 |
+-----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Now My Query should BE SOMETHING LIKE..

> ```
> SELECT USERNAME FROM PLAYERS 
> IF 
>  (DIFFERENCE BETWEEN A & B <20)
>
> IF
>  (DIFFERENCE BETWEEN C & D <20)
>
> IF
>  (DIFFERENCE BETWEEN E & F <20)
> IF
>  (DIFFERENCE BETWEEN G & H <20)
> ```

Now .. I have to select username if any two out of four conditions are true..
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed SQL Server

```
select
   username 
from(
    SELECT USERNAME,
        case when abs(a-b)<20 then 1 else 0 end A
        case when abs(c-d)<20 then 1 else 0 end b
        case when abs(e-f)<20 then 1 else 0 end c
        case when abs(g-h)<20 then 1 else 0 end d
    FROM PLAYERS
)tmp
WHERE tmp.a+tmp.b+tmp.c+tmp.d>=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mysql:

```
select username from (
    select username,
        if(b-a < 20, 1, 0) as ab,
        if(d-c < 20, 1, 0) as cd,
        if(f-e < 20, 1, 0) as ef,
        if(h-g < 20, 1, 0) as gh
    from players
) x where ab + cd + ef + gh = 2
```

You may want to use `abs()` if a can be higher than b.  You may want to use `>= 2` if two or more conditions are fine.